# Same dash dashboard template with different dataset inside a flask app. How to do it?

Tags: plotly-dash, dashboard

I'm looking for the simplest way to generate the same dash dashboard X times with different dataset.
Each dashboard is a single page and the main app is a flask app.

The goal is to have a dashboard template running on different dash instance with different dataset.

I started with the following code, but I'm struggling when dash pages include callbacks i.e when `html.Div([html.H1('Hi there, I am app1 for reports')])` turns into a bigger function with callback

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
    
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello from Flask!'

@app.route('/test2')
def t2():
    return render_template('test2.html')

dash_app1 = dash.Dash(__name__, server = app, url_base_pathname='/dashboard/' )
dash_app2 = dash.Dash(__name__, server = app, url_base_pathname='/reports/')
dash_app1.layout = html.Div([html.H1('Hi there, I am app1 for reports')])
dash_app2.layout = html.Div([html.H1('Hi there, I am app2 for reports')])

@app.route('/dashboard')
def render_dashboard():
    return redirect('/dash1')

@app.route('/reports')
def render_reports():
    return redirect('/dash2')

app = DispatcherMiddleware(app, {
    '/dash1': dash_app1.server,
    '/dash2': dash_app2.server
})
```

So my question is what is the best way/architecture to manage muti dash dashboards, based on the same template, running different data ?

Answer (score 1):

In case it might help, I found a solution encapsulating the layout, callbacks and return function into a class.

flask_app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect
import dash

from apps.dashboard1 import Dashboard1
from apps.dashboard2 import Dashboard2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello from Flask!'

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return render_template('test.html')

 
dash_app1 = dash.Dash(__name__, server = app, url_base_pathname='/dashboard1/' )
dash_app1.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
dash_app1.layout = Dashboard1(dash_app1).layout
@app.route('/dashboard1')
def render_dashboard():
    return redirect('/dash1')


dash_app2 = dash.Dash(__name__, server = app, url_base_pathname='/dashboard2/')
dash_app2.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
dash_app2.layout = Dashboard2(dash_app2).layout
@app.route('/dashboard2')
def render_dashboard2():
    return redirect('/dash2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

apps/dashboard1.py

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

class Dashboard1:
    def __init__(self, app_dependency):
        self.app_dependency = app_dependency

        html.P("Your code here"),
            dcc.Dropdown(...),
            ...
            dcc.Graph(id="pie-chart"),
        ])


        @self.app_dependency.callback(
            Output("pie-chart", "figure"),
            Input('organisations', 'value'))

        def update_output_div(selected_org):
            your_update_function
            return  your_outputs
```